# SASS + Compass - File Structure and @Import order

Tags: css, sass

I recently started using SASS and Compass in my projects. So far I am using the file structure shown below.

```
  sass/ 
    | 
    |– base/ 
    |   |– _reset.scss       # Reset/normalize 
    |   |– _typography.scss  # Typography rules 
    |   ...                  # Etc… 
    | 
    |– components/ 
    |   |– _buttons.scss     # Buttons 
    |   |– _carousel.scss    # Carousel 
    |   |– _cover.scss       # Cover 
    |   |– _dropdown.scss    # Dropdown 
    |   |– _navigation.scss  # Navigation 
    |   ...                  # Etc… 
    | 
    |– helpers/ 
    |   |– _variables.scss   # Sass Variables 
    |   |– _functions.scss   # Sass Functions 
    |   |– _mixins.scss      # Sass Mixins 
    |   |– _helpers.scss     # Class & placeholders helpers 
    |   ...                  # Etc… 
    | 
    |– layout/ 
    |   |– _grid.scss        # Grid system 
    |   |– _header.scss      # Header 
    |   |– _footer.scss      # Footer 
    |   |– _sidebar.scss     # Sidebar 
    |   |– _forms.scss       # Forms 
    |   ...                  # Etc… 
    | 
    |– pages/ 
    |   |– _home.scss        # Home specific styles 
    |   |– _contact.scss     # Contact specific styles 
    |   ...                  # Etc… 
    | 
    |– vendors/ 
    |   |– _bootstrap.scss   # Bootstrap 
    |   |– _jquery-ui.scss   # jQuery UI 
    |   ...                  # Etc… 
    | 
    | 
    `– main.scss             # primary Sass file
```

I am happy with the file structure *(unless anyone would like to comment on how it could be improved)*

**My issue is:** **I am not entirely sure what the best practice is for ordering my @Imports in Primary SCSS file.**

I was wondering if anyone could advise me on the best way to import.

I have not yet put together my imports for this new file structure, yet I will show my imports for a previous project.

**Previous Project's Primary SCSS file:**

```
@import "partials/defaults";
@import "partials/typography";
@import "partials/grids";
@import "partials/buttons";
@import "partials/headers";
@import "partials/footers";
```

I want to know which practice is best for organizing my new file structure.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: slightly confused as to why my question is flagged as off topic, I was simply showing my structure and code and seeing if there was a cleaner or better alternative, maybe it's the way I worded it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way works, but it is not very scalable, since you have to compile all the sass files every time you make a change, this is time consuming when the project gets bigger.

here you watch all the files via grunt/gulp, but only compile the _watchables, the _procompiled file is compiled upon start of server only, not during file watch.

when building for production, use `build.scss` to build the final css file, the build contains the watchables and precompiled files.

the _globals file will contain global configurations, styleguide variables, and functions/mixins. the global file does not have css in it, only utilities and functions, and is imported in both watchables and precompiled files.

## Structure

```
.style
├── build.scss
├── _globals.scss
├── _watchables.scss
├── _precompiled.scss
├── vendors
|   ├── index.scss
|   └── _bootstrap.scss
├── helpers
|   ├── index.scss
|   └── _variables.scss
```

## build.scss

```
@include '_globals.scss';
@include '_precompiled.scss';
@include '_watchables.scss';
```

## _precompiled.scss

```
//contains vendor files and other unchanged scss files.
@include '_globals.scss';
@include 'vendor/_index.scss';
```

## _watchables.scss

```
//contains the files you want to build everytime you save
@include '_globals.scss';
@include 'pages/homepage.scss';
```

## any index.scss file

```
//include everything in the folder.
@include '_bootstrap.scss';
```

I developed this way while working on a big project with my company, the build time got reduced from 8ms per file save to less than a second. i was compiling only the pages folder in my watchables.scss file, since the rest of the files are almost always stable, but sometimes i include a component in my watchables to develop the component then put it back to the precompiled file.

Comment: I will try this, much appreciated.